# Google sign in API does not work on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-signin

I am currently handling a web app that requires the user to sign in using their google account to gain access to the core functionalities. When using *Google Chrome* everything works the way it's expected to work: The user clicks "Sign In", a pop-up opens with Google sign in form, the user signs in, and he will be transferred to the main page. (good)

**HOWEVER**

When using Mozilla Firefox 38.0.1, the web app cannot be used in any way because when the user clicks "Sign In", it does nothing. Literally nothing, not even an error on the console.

Here is the login button:

```
//head
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="{CLIENT ID}.apps.googleusercontent.com">

//body
<button class="g-signin2 login-button" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></button>
```

Is there a currently known issue with Firefox and Google Sign In API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found the solution: I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners). Basically, I didnt use the easy integration of the Google SignIn and I just created a custom handler and listeners. I kept the original buttons because it is required and just added this javascript:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plus.js?onload=appStart"></script>
```

**JS**

```
//googleSignIn.js

var auth2; // The Sign-In object.
var googleUser; // The current user.
/**
 * Calls startAuth after Sign in V2 finishes setting up.
 */
var appStart = function() {
  console.log('appStart()')
  gapi.load('auth2', initSigninV2);
};
/**
 * Initializes Signin v2 and sets up listeners.
 */
var initSigninV2 = function() {
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance({
      client_id: '{CLIENT ID}.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      scope: 'profile'
  });

  // Listen for sign-in state changes.
  auth2.isSignedIn.listen(signinChanged);
  // Listen for changes to current user.
  auth2.currentUser.listen(userChanged);

  // Sign in the user if they are currently signed in.
  if (auth2.isSignedIn.get() == true) {
      auth2.signIn();
  }
};
/**
 * Listener method for sign-out live value.
 *
 * @param {boolean} val the updated signed out state.
 */
var signinChanged = function (val) {
    console.log('Signin state changed to ', val);
};
/**
 * Listener method for when the user changes.
 *
 * @param {GoogleUser} user the updated user.
 */
var userChanged = function (user) {
  console.log('User now: ', user);
  googleUser = user;
};

$('.login-button').on('click', function() {
    console.log('signing in')

    auth2.signIn().then(function(user) {
        //callback to handle sign in
        onSignIn(user);
    });
})
```

I'm not sure what caused the issue of the Google Sign In to not work on mozilla. If anyone knows this to be a known issue please let me know in the comments.

**Bottomline:** [easy integration](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) of Google Sign In did not work on Mozilla. Had to [integrate using listeners](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners).

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you.

Comment: Useful. Mine didn't work because I was using the `/js/client:platform.js` script.